# SQL QUERY TO Get Pivot data in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that is giving me output like follows -

```
SELECT distinct KD.course_name,
KD.lrnr_pnum,
(substr(KD.qustn,1,instr(KD.qustn,'.',1,1))) qustn,
(KD.answr) answr,
(KD.comnt) commt,
( kd.INTERACTION_CREATION_DATE) INTERACTION_CREATION_DATE,
KD.seq

from SCORM_DATA KD
WHERE KD.ATTEMPT_END_DATE = (SELECT MAX(ATTEMPT_END_DATE)
 from SCORM_DATA KD1
WHERE KD1.course_name = KD.course_name
AND KD1.lrnr_pnum = KD.lrnr_pnum
and KD.lrnr_pnum='10'
```

This gives me output like -

```
lrnr_pnum    qustn                               answr              commt         INTERACTION_CREATION_DATE          seq  

10            what is your pets name            tommy                testing             29-mar-2022                 1
10            what is your  name                Rhea                yes                  29-mar-2022                 2
10            what is your  school               ZYX                fav                  28-mar-2022                 3
```

Now i want the questions to display like

```
pnum            que_1               ans_1            comm_1         que_2                   ans_2       comm_2     ques_3      ans_3   comm_3
   
10       what is your pets name     tommy           testing    what is your  name           Rhea        yes       what is your  school

ZYX         fav
```

I used pivot for this   -

```
SELECT distinct KD.course_name,
KD.lrnr_pnum,
(substr(KD.qustn,1,instr(KD.qustn,'.',1,1))) qustn,
(KD.answr) answr,
(KD.comnt) commt,
( kd.INTERACTION_CREATION_DATE) INTERACTION_CREATION_DATE,
KD.seq

from SCORM_DATA KD
WHERE KD.ATTEMPT_END_DATE = (SELECT MAX(ATTEMPT_END_DATE)
 from SCORM_DATA KD1
WHERE KD1.course_name = KD.course_name
AND KD1.lrnr_pnum = KD.lrnr_pnum
and KD.lrnr_pnum='10'

pivot ( max(qustn) AS q_txt, max(answr) AS a_txt, max(commt) AS c_txt 
FOR seq IN (1 AS q1 ,
                                                                                                                                                          2  AS q2,
                                                                                                                                                          3  AS q3) )
```

But this is giving me the following output -

```
pnum            que_1               ans_1            comm_1         que_2                   ans_2       comm_2     ques_3       ans_3   comm_3
   
10       what is your pets name     tommy           testing
10                                                             what is your  name           Rhea        yes       
10                                                                                                              what is your fav school    ZYX
```

How can i use pivot but get the output in one row instead ?

Comment: max of each pivoted value and group by pnum

Comment: I have already done max of each pivoted value. Adding group by should solve this ?

Comment: even if i add group by it gave me same output

Answer (score 0):

Table spec -

```
create table tst_pvt(lrnr_pnum number,
qustn varchar2(100),
answr varchar2(100),
commt varchar2(100),
INTERACTION_CREATION_DATE date,
seq number
);
```

Inserted dummy data -

```
insert into tst_pvt values (10,'what is your pets name','tommy','testing','29-MAR-22',1);
insert into tst_pvt values (10,'what is your name','Rhea','yes','29-MAR-22',2);
insert into tst_pvt values (10,'what is your school','ZYX','fav','28-mar-2022',3);
```

## Query for PIVOT

```
select lrnr_pnum,
"1_QT" as que1,"1_AN" as ans1, "1_CM" as comm1, 
"2_QT" as que2,"2_AN" as ans2, "2_CM" as comm2,
"3_QT" as que3,"3_AN" as ans3, "3_CM" as comm3 
from 
(select lrnr_pnum,qustn,answr,commt,seq from tst_pvt t)
pivot
(
max(qustn) as qt
,max(answr) as an
,max(commt) as cm
for (seq) in (1,2,3)
);
```